# How to add library dependency additionally for exact plugin during execution?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4" withSources() withJavadoc()
```

and this

```
//Liquibase

liquibaseUsername := "postgres"

liquibasePassword := "postgres"

liquibaseDriver   := "org.posgresql.Driver"

liquibaseUrl      := "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/scala_app"

liquibaseChangelog := "src/main/liquibase/db.changelog.xml"

seq(LiquibasePlugin.liquibaseSettings: _*)
```

But after

```
cmd > liquibase-status
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to C:\Users\mstrokov\mstr\workspaces\other\spring-mvc-hiber-scala\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:liquibaseDatabase for the full output.
[error] (*:liquibaseDatabase) liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.
posgresql.Driver
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 19-Nov-2014 11:58:07
```

and I know that I should specify my jdbc driver dependency exactly for plugin too.

My question is how I can do this?

**EDIT:** 
My problem was in mistyping in 'org.posgresql.Driver'. I missed letter 't' in 'posTgresql'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the it to `libraryDependenies` in `projects/build.sbt` and it should work.

The reason is that sbt is recursive, so `PROJECT_DIR/build.sbt` defines stuff together with `project/*.scala` build files, and `project/*.sbt` are in the same way defining settings for `project/project` - the project that builds the project.

You can read more about that here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Full-Def.html